# SAS ERROR from GOPTIONS?

Tags: sas

I'm writing SAS code and experiencing an error that seems to be caused by SAS generated language in code.  I've been using SAS awhile and never experienced this.  Any help/advice would be appreciated.  I've cut out some of the middle code so this is not so long.

```
1          ;*';*";*/;quit;run;
2          OPTIONS PAGENO=MIN;
3          %LET _CLIENTTASKLABEL='Program';
4          %LET _CLIENTPROJECTPATH='Z:\ACS\Decision Sciences\Analysis\Code\AAU_Analysis.egp';
5          %LET _CLIENTPROJECTNAME='AAU_Analysis.egp';
6          %LET _SASPROGRAMFILE=;
7          
8          ODS _ALL_ CLOSE;
9          OPTIONS DEV=ACTIVEX;
10         FILENAME EGSR TEMP;
11         ODS tagsets.sasreport13(ID=EGSR) FILE=EGSR
12             STYLE=HtmlBlue
13             STYLESHEET=(URL="file:///C:/Program%20Files/SASHome/SASEnterpriseGuide/6.1/Styles/HtmlBlue.css")
14             NOGTITLE
15             NOGFOOTNOTE
16             GPATH=&sasworklocation
17             ENCODING=UTF8
18             options(rolap="on")
19         ;
NOTE: Writing TAGSETS.SASREPORT13(EGSR) Body file: EGSR
20         
21         options nomprint nomlogic;
22         
23         libname acs 'F:\SAS_data\ACS';
NOTE: Libref ACS was successfully assigned as follows: 
      Engine:        V9 
      Physical Name: F:\SAS_data\ACS
24         %include 'F:\SAS_data\Lysbet\sas_macro_library.sas';
171              
173        %macro transform_survey;
174        
175        data acs.aau_data_transformed;
176        set acs.aau_data;
177        length brand $3.;

189        %do i=1 %to 10;
190         antonym_pair=&i;
191         %do j = 1 %to &n;
192             %let val = %scan(&lst, &j);
193             brand=&val;
194             suppress_flag1=Q12&val.Flag1;
195             suppress_flag2=Q12&val.Flag2;
196             score=Q_12&val._&i;
197             output;
198         %end;
199         brand='ACS';
200         score=Q_9_&i;
201         output;
202        %end;
205        %mend;
206        %transform_survey;
207        
208        %LET _CLIENTTASKLABEL=;
209        %LET _CLIENTPROJECTPATH=;
210        %LET _CLIENTPROJECTNAME=;
211        %LET _SASPROGRAMFILE=;
212        
213        ;*';*";*/;quit;run;
                 ____
                 180

ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.
```

Comment: Check the file that you included. Also perhaps some lines are truncating? Try adding the SOURCE2 and/or LRECL option to the include statement.  `%include 'F:\SAS_data\Lysbet\sas_macro_library.sas' /source2 lrecl=32767 ;`

Answer (score 0):

That means somewhere (probably in the included macro library, or in previously submitted code) you have an unmatched quote (or unmatched %macro/%mend or other similar pair, but it looks like `"` if you have things lined up correctly).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all input but classic case of user error.  I forgot the run statement for the data step in my macro.  I knew it was going to end up being something seemingly unrelated.